# parsing words in a document using specific delimiters

Tags: string, delimiter, text-parsing

I have a document that I'm parsing words from but I want to consider anything that is not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or an apostrophe, to be white space. How could I do this if I am using the following bit of code before:

```
ifstream file;
file.open(filePath);

while(file >> word){
    listOfWords.push_back(word); // I want to make sure only words with the stated 
                                 // range of characters exist in my list.
}
```

So, for example, the word hor.se would be two elements in my list, "hor" and "se".

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of "whitespace characters" and then each time you encounter a character, check to see if that character is in the list and if so you've started a new word. This example is written in python, but the concept is the same.

```
def get_words(whitespace_chars, string):
    words = []
    current_word = ""
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
        #check to see if we hit the end of a word.                                                                                                                                                                                           
        if(string[x] in whitespace_chars and current_word != ""):
            words.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
        #add current letter to current word.                                                                                     
        else:
            current_word += string[x]
    #if the last letter isnt whitespace then the last word wont be added, so add here.                                                                                                                                                       
    if(current_word != ""):
        words.append(current_word)
    return words
```

return words